# Is there a traceroute command for VXWorks? Specifically a Shoretel Phone?

Tags: networking, voip, shoretel

I can't seem to find if there is a traceroute command for VXworks online or specifically with a Shoretel phone. Once I telnet into the phone, I would like the ability to see whether packets from my VPN phones are taking the correct path back to my switch.

Answer (score 1):

You could try `tracert "destination.ip"`

Some other helpful commands might be:

`ping`("ip.address",#of pings to send) ie. `ping("10.1.2.3",5)`
`routeShow()` - show the current routing table.